# Opening php files in sublime text 2

Tags: mamp, sublimetext2

Is there a way to open .php files locally with sublime text 2?
I created three builds for each browser but when used they just get sent to my download folder. I am testing Coda 2 and it works! I have MAMP Pro installed as well; Is that messing with sublime?